# If $\omega=\cos(2\pi/n)+i\sin(2\pi/n)$, what are the distinct $n$th roots of 1?

Tags: abstract-algebra, roots-of-unity

My work so far:

$\omega^1=\cos(2\pi/n)+i\sin(2\pi/n)=e^{i(2\pi/n)}$

$\omega^2 =e^{i(4\pi/n)}$

$\omega^{n-1} =e^{i(2(n-1)\pi/n)}$

$\omega^n =e^{i(2\pi)}$

These appear to be the distinct $n$th roots, but I am  having troubles determining how to explicitly show that they are.

Comment: Hint: $\omega^{n+1}=\omega$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For $0\le k\lt n$, $\left(e^{2\pi ik/n}\right)^n=e^{2\pi ik}=1$, so they are all $n^\text{th}$ roots of $1$.

Given $0\le j\lt k\lt n$
$$
\frac{e^{2\pi ik/n}}{e^{2\pi ij/n}}=e^{2\pi i(k-j)/n}\ne1
$$
so they are all different.

Comment: Where did you get the $k$ and $j$ from?

Comment: $e^{2\pi ij/n}=\omega^j$ and $e^{2\pi ik/n}=\omega^k$ are two of the powers of $\omega=e^{2\pi i/n}$ that you have listed.

Comment: I see. I have two remaining questions for you: (1) how do you know that $e^{2\pi ik}=1$, and (2) how do you know that $e^{2 \pi i(k-j/n} \ne 1$?

Comment: (1) Since $e^{2\pi i}=1$, any integral power is also $1$.  (2) $e^{2\pi i(k-j)/n}=\cos\left(2\pi i\frac{k-j}n\right)+i\sin\left(2\pi i\frac{k-j}n\right)\ne1+0i$ unless $\frac{k-j}n\in\mathbb{Z}$.

Comment: Wonderful- thank you for your help!

Answer (score 2):

$(\omega^k)^n=(\omega^n)^k=1^k=1$

Comment: It might be that OP also wants to show that $\{1,\omega,\ldots,\omega^{n-1}\}$ are all distinct.

Comment: Yes, that is one of my main objectives in this post. This simple property does help, however.